# Unity PlayMode tests - cannot find UnityEngine.InputSystem assembly

Tags: unity, input, testing, unit-testing

I'm trying to simulate user input in my Unity PlayMode tests. I've been reading [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Testing.html) guide on the Unity website about adding input simulation into my tests. Specifically, it mentions I need to add the `Unity.InputSystem` and `Unity.InputSystem.TestFramework` assemblies as references in my PlayMode assembly. However, I can't find these assemblies (see image below).

[image: missing assembly]

I suspect I'm missing a step on bringing these assemblies into Unity to reference them, but I can't find any further documentation on this.

Comment: Have you imported the InputSystem package into your project in the Package Manager window?

Comment: Ah, that was it! I had seen that in the Package Manager previously, but noted that it listed it as a new input system. I've been using `Input.GetKeyDown` style methods so far, so I may need to revisit input in general as part of this. But that has added the assemblies I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Want to post your solution as an Answer? Particularly once you've worked through the change to integrate the new system, seeing an end-to-end guide could help the next person searching for how to test input.

Comment: Or, if you find porting your existing code to use the new Input System is too onerous, we could probably find a way to make a testable wrapper around the legacy Input Manager.

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a go of moving to the new input system, as it appears that is the direction Unity is going. I did consider using a testable wrapper but didn't want to overcomplicate the codebase just for the sake of the tests. I have used public methods on the components as a workaround, but this should allow me to follow the proper input simulation approach. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to resolve this issue, with some direction. I hadn't realised that the Input System test framework I was trying to use, was actually part of a package I hadn't yet installed: the new Unity Input System. Reading further back on [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Testing.html) guide that I posted in the question, I realised there was an [installation step](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Installation.html) I had missed that directed me to install the Input System package.

With this package now installed, I was able to inherit my test class from `TestInputFixture`, which handles the initialization of a clean, temporary input system. This was my setup:

```
public class MyTests : InputTestFixture
{
    private Keyboard keyboard;

    [SetUp]
    public override void Setup()
    {
        base.Setup();

        keyboard = InputSystem.AddDevice<Keyboard>();
    }
}
```

I was then able to simulate key presses in my tests:

```
[UnityTest]
public IEnumerator MyTest()
{
    Press(keyboard.escapeKey);
    Release(keyboard.escapeKey);
    yield return null;

    // ... assertions
}
```

One point to note here is that I wanted to check if the key had been pressed on that frame (not that it was being held down). This is the same as using the classic `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)`. As a result, I needed to ensure my test simulated not just pressing the key down, but also releasing it back up, all within the same frame to register as being pressed on that frame.

My actual code method could then check for this scenario with the following:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Keyboard.current.escapeKey.wasPressedThisFrame)
    {
        // ... do the thing
    }
}
```

One point to note here, is that this is fine for a simple scenario like this, but only supports a single input device. The recommended approach is to actually move away from checking input manually within the `Update()` method, and instead making use of the `PlayerInput` mechanism that binds actions, input and scripts through the editor. You can read more about this [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/QuickStartGuide.html#getting-input-indirectly-through-an-input-action).

Thanks to @DMGregory for pointing me in the right direction.